# cannot serialize/de-serialize java.time.Instant field

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices

I have 2 spring boot based microservices which interact through events. Producer microservice sends an event which is a POJO to RabbitMQ queue. Consumer microservice listens to the queue. The POJO has 2 java.time.Instant fields which spoils the serialization/de-serialization process. For now I have commented out these fields & it is working.
I have tried by declaring a Jackson2JsonMessageConverter bean:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .findAndRegisterModules().disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
}
```

Here is the stack trace which states that the problem is with Instant fields.

```
    org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:116) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1383) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1667) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1442) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1284) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1693) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1583) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at brave.spring.rabbit.TracingRabbitListenerAdvice.invoke(TracingRabbitListenerAdvice.java:100) ~[brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit-5.9.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.$Proxy274.invokeListener(Unknown Source) ~[na:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:303) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:259) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:302) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:323) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:122) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:205) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:132) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.Instant` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"tableTypeDtos":[{"tableTypeId":581,"gameTableTemplateId":17,"tableName":"T0150","rakeId":2,"currencyId":2,"createdThrough":"System","tableCreationType":"Now","createdBy":"admin","updatedBy":"admin","domain":1,"statusId":1,"createdDate":{"nano":717661000,"epochSecond":1638864164},"updatedDate":{"nano":717661000,"epochSecond":1638864164}},{"tableTypeId":582,"gameTableTemplateId":17,"tableName":"T0151","rakeId":2,"currencyId":2,"createdThrough":"System","tableCreationType":"Now","createdBy":"admi"[truncated 250 chars]; line: 1, column: 240] (through reference chain: com.blockgemini.bkpoker.service.gms.domain.broker.message.CreateTablesBrokerMessage["tableTypeDtos"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.blockgemini.bkpoker.service.gms.domain.dto.TableTypeDto["createdDate"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1589) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1055) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:286) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3205) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/:2.10.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertBytesToObject(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:311) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:292) ~[spring-amqp-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

So what to do? Should I go for LocalDateTime in place of Instant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And then you need to customize your `ObjectMapper` as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        return new ObjectMapper().registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dias, thanks. It is working